# Change the file name for google spreadsheet when downloaded as TSV

Tags: html, google-sheets

I have a published google spreadsheet and would like it to download as a specific file name when I download it as a TSV. The name of the file when downloaded is the name of my sheet + `- Template.tsv`. I need a way of changing this setting on the google end because this file will be downloaded via an HTML form, so I won't have the option to manually change the file name.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the filename cannot be changed by the query parameters. So it is required to use a script for downloading.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it a programming question. In it's current state it looks to be off-topic for this site. Ref. [ask].